# Omxplayer live RTSP / ffmpeg record

Tags: raspbian, omxplayer, ffmpeg

I have a problem on my rpi 3 b+, when i record the screen using this

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 30 -s cif -i :0.0 /tmp/out.mpg
```

it was able to record it properly but when **omxplayer plays RTSP**.
it doesn't record what omxplayer showing but only the desktop.

> rpi config

- 256mb vid
- no gl (omxplayer wont play if full / fake gl)
- rtsp cam

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Did you fire that command with `root` user?

Comment: thanks, and yes i did sudo / root and the output still the same, ffmpeg record only desktop ignoring omxplayer rtsp display / feed.

ps. i use hdmi as my primary display

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg x11grab` will only record what's being put on the screen by X11. `omxplayer` is configured to use OMX hardware acceleration interface (hence the name), which will not be recorded.

You can record a playback from a video player supporting the X11 video output (e.g. `vlc video.avi -V x11`), but bear in mind that the X11 playback will be much slower than hardware decoding.